# Behavior of <select> tag on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html-select

I set the color of select tag to red and it behaves normal as i expected, however when the number of option tag is over 300 the color is not working, it behaves as the browser agent is,

What is the problem and how i can fix this issue?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google developers thought nobody would put more than 300 items in a select dropdown so to improve performance they turned off css styling if you exceeded it. After much uproar they are removing that restriction in v45.
[see this Link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so i can not fix this issue by codes or with some other ways the only way is to upgrade chrome?

Comment: This problem was fixed on Chrome 45. if you upgraded your chrome this problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UTLtq/)

```css
select{
  background:transparent;
   width: 170px;
   padding: 2px;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:11px;
   font-weight:600;
   color:#fff;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 22px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 
  }

.select-div{
 width: 170px;
 height: 22px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url(arrowhead.png) no-repeat right #363636;
 border-top:#575757 1px solid;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(107, 105, 105, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 8px 3px -9px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 3px -9px #000000;
    box-shadow:         0px 8px 3px -9px #000000;
}

select > option {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-div">
        <select name="pagination">
          <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: I agree with Hassan, this issue exists only when option item is over 300 thanks all the same